# Style of the Dialog like in EditTextPreference

Tags: android, dialog

Is there any way to make dialog like in *EditTextPreference* outside of *PreferenceActivity*?
Let's say I want this dialog to appear on button click in my main *Activity*.

I've tried to build a *Dialog* with a custom layout but I don't know how to make it exactly the same as in *EditTextPreference*.

[image: Screenshot of the window I'm talking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, basically all you need is an `AlertDialog` with an `EditText` as a child view.
Short example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
adb.setTitle("My title");
adb.setView(input);
adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String inputText = input.getText().toString();
                // Do something with the input here             
            }

        });
adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
adb.show();
```

All you do here is creating an `EditText` instance in code and set it as the dialogs content via `setView()`. Just make it final so you can access it from the anonymous `OnClickListener` in this example. Of course you can refactor that a bit, but I think it's already pretty handy.

*`this` is referencing a `Context` here. Since you are calling the dialog from an `Activity` (extends `Context`), you should be fine.*